# Select a distinct attribute with maximum shape area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, sql, select-by-attribute

I am trying to manipulate a large dataset containing a lot of sliver polygons resulting from an overlay operations. (The eliminate tool is very time consuming to generalize them.)

I identified the sliver polygons using:

```
SELECT * FROM data1 WHERE
  [CODE] IN ( SELECT CODE 
              FROM data1 
              GROUP BY CODE 
              HAVING Count ( CODE ) >1)
```

Now I want to select the slivers with maximum area from the ones isolated through above query.

I need to select each CODE value (from the multiple instances) where the associated shape area is the largest. This will help me eliminate the sliver polygons without having to merge them separately.

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: Which tool are you working with?

Comment: I am using Eliminate in Arcinfo 9.3. Even after using it, there are some sliver polygons leftover. The best chance i have to accurately remove them is to select the one with maximum area in repeating 'code' values. I have Postgresql 8.4 as well.